# Accessing embedded resources in Wix DTF Custom Action

Tags: wix, wix3.7

My DTF project contains some embedded resources and I would like to access the same in the CustomAction.

I tried the following code in the Custom Action method

```
// Gets the current assembly.
Assembly Asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// Resources are named using a fully qualified name.
Stream strm = Asm.GetManifestResourceStream(Asm.GetName().Name + "." + Name);
```

However this doesnt work as Asm always refers to the Wix Setup assembly and not the custom action dll which contains the resources

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CustomAction));`, to get the assembly that contains your custom action?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure this scenario is possible. I mean, there might be no option (or no easy option) to get the custom action executing assembly and extract the resources out of it.

Instead of this, I would try to re-design the solution and move resources to the [Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367825.aspx) table in MSI package. Thus, you'll still have embedded resources, but not in CA DLL, but in the MSI package itself. The DTF.chm help file contains a sample how to extract files from Binary table - it's a matter of a couple of lines of code.